# How to include more than one argument in raw_input()?

Tags: python, raw-input

I am very new at coding so sorry if my code bellow annoys you lol but I was wondering if there is any way to include more than 1 argument in the raw_input() function so that I wouldn't have to do

```
print("Do you want to filter numbers greater or lower that ", filt, "?")
gorl = raw_input()
```

rather than just

```
gorl = raw_input("Do you want to filter numbers greater or lower than ", 
filt, "?")
```

my entire code is

```
import random
import sys
import os

filt = int(raw_input("What number do you want your results to be filtered 
by?"))

gorl = raw_input("Do you want to filter numbers greater or lower than ", 
filt, "?")

ammvar = int(raw_input("How many variables do you want to filter?"))

var_list = []

varnum = 1

while ammvar > 0:
    var_list.append(int(raw_input("Variable ", varnum, ":")))
    varnum + 1
    ammvar - 1
```

and this is what eclipse returns when I run it

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
What number do you want your results to be filtered by?10

Do you want it to be filtered greater or lower?greater

How many variables do you want to filter?7

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\D\workspace\Simple\Sorter__init__.py", line 16, in

var_list.append(int(raw_input("Variable ", varnum, ":")))

TypeError: raw_input() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: `raw_input("Do you want to filter numbers greater or lower than {} ?".format(filt))`

Comment: `print()` explicitly takes a variable number of arguments, writing them all out as strings with a separator between. `raw_input()` doesn't do that, just for a single string first. You could use string templates (`str.format()`) or concatenation for that. Or just print without a newline at the end with `print(...., end='')` then run a `raw_input()` command with no string.

Comment: Use string formatting to insert parameters into strings.

Comment: Ok, didn't think about that sorry, thank you so much!

Comment: See [format-examples](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples)